# How to provide an option to save username and password to iCloud Keychain on iOS in NativeScript Angular?

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am working on a NativeScript iOS app. The app has a login page which requires users to login before they can use the app. I just wanted to add more convenience for the users to not have to type in the username and password everytime. So, I added the [nativescript-fingerprint-auth plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript/fingerprint-auth) to enable touch/face id, which is working fine.

Now, I also wanted the app to provide an option to save the password to Keychain on the initial login and provide an option to autofill the password in the next login. Much like shown in the screenshot. So any kind of information regarding this would be helpful.

Thank you in advance!

[image]
[img source](https://www.copytrans.net/blog/how-to-setup-and-use-icloud-keychain-on-iphone/)